# Generating text box in php and codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I want to dynamically generate a row of text boxes in a table when clicking a button.For example i have  a table to enter the list items.When i click add button, a new row is inserted into the table.Can you please help me.I am working on php and codeigniter..

The foolowing is the script which I have used for generating the row.

```
<SCRIPT language="javascript">
function changeIt()
{
var i = 1;
my_div.innerHTML = my_div.innerHTML +"<br><input type='text' name='mytext'+ i>"

i++;
}
</SCRIPT>

<table align="center" name="table">
<tr>
<td>Code</td>
<td>Name</td>
<td>Quantity</td>
<td>Price</td>
<INPUT type="button" value="Add" onclick="changeIt()"/>
</tr>
</table>
<div id="my_div">
<table>
<tr>
<td></td>
</tr>
</table>
```

This only generates one text box at a time. I need to display more that one text box in a row?

Comment: what you have tried so far?

Comment: i will post the code now.

Comment: i have pasted the code as an answer here.

Comment: Ravi, please post code in question & not in answer. Remove your answer & add code in question. Also, what is `my_div`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this (New Code)

```
<SCRIPT language="javascript">
var i = 1;
function changeIt()
{
    var my_div = document.getElementById("my_div");
    var row = "<tr> <td> <input type='text' name='mycode_"+i+"'></td><td><input type='text' name='myname_"+i+"'></td><td><input type='text' name='myquantity_"+i+"'></td> <td><input type='text' name='myprice_"+i+"'></td> </tr>";
    my_div.innerHTML = my_div.innerHTML +row;
    i++;
}
</SCRIPT>

<table align="center" name="table" id="my_div" border="2">
<tr>
<td>Code</td>
<td>Name</td>
<td>Quantity</td>
<td>Price</td>
<INPUT type="button" value="Add" onclick="changeIt()"/>
</tr>
</table>
```

Comment: tried this.but unfortunately doesn't display any text box now.

Comment: is it because of error in my html code?<div id="my_div">
<table>
<tr>
<td></td>
</tr>
</table></div>

Comment: yes u have to define the my_div in script, sry i forgot to implment it in above. please add this code 
var my_div = document.getElementById("my_table"); // this must id of the table

Comment: still not working.sad.i think there is error in the script.i mean quotes error.quotes are missing.

Comment: can you please tell me how to get the values of these text boxes in php.

Comment: Get the table inside "form" and get input values when form is submitted.

Answer (score 0):

You can try [jQuery append method](http://api.jquery.com/append/) or row javascript -> [HTML DOM appendChild() Method](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_node_appendchild.asp/)